# How to add "Using " statement at runtime using IWizard

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, vsix, visual-studio-extensions

at compile time we have

```
using MyNamespace;
```

This works till now but recently the requirement got change and it needs to handle at run time based on the application type selected by the user.

So, How can I add the "Using" namespace statement using c# code in the IWizard?

I know how to add the reference at run time ass under

```
 var appProject = project.Object as VSProject;
 appProject.References.Add(Mydll);
```

What I want is that at runtime

```
using System.IO;
using MyNamespace-> should come at runtime based on the application selected
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just hit a similar issue and while it is not exactly changing the namespace at run time it does all you to get objects etc from a different namespace at run time.  If you want to be changing namespaces chances are you have classes with the same names and interfaces but different implementations otherwise your code would need to be changed.  What you need to do if make a new lib and namespace that just contains the interfaces for all the classes you want to use.  You then make the classes in the different namespaces inherit these interfaces so you can code your class to just use the interface not the particular implementation.  Then to select the implementation to use at run time you use "Dependancy Injection" to choose the correct implementation to insert via config file or let some other part of your application configure the injection. Dependancy Injection can be a little hard to get started with but once you get your head around it, it will make your life a lot easier.  Ninject is a nice easy dependancy injection framework to start with.